# Upgraded WinForms project from VS2005 to VS2012. Now my ReportViewer DLLs are missing

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005, reportviewer

I got a copy of a Visual Studio 2005 project from a friend. The project referenced the DLLs Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms. On my machine I have Visual Studio 2012. I upgraded the project. The references to these DLLs are broken, understandably, because they are Windows locations, not in the VS project. So, I want to delete the references and re-create, but I cannot find the DLLs on my machine. Do they not get installed with Visual Studio 2012? Can I download them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These have been replaced by Report Server. Though if you'd copy them over from your VS2005 machine you should still be able to use them as binary references in your solution. You can [download the binaries from the MSDN Download site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916).

Though there should be [binaries for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747) as well. I suspect they will get installed when you install the [SQL Server Development tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2013/03/06/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2012-released-online.aspx), which include the SQL Server Reporting Server components.

Answer (score 1):

> I got a copy of a Visual Studio 2005 project from a friend

Which explains the problem, the target .NET version of your project is 2.0.  The ReportViewer included with VS2012 requires at least 3.5.

Fix it with Project + Properties, Application tab, Target Framework combobox.  You'll then find the ReportViewer control back under the "Reporting" header in the toolbox.

Comment: I don't think I can do this. The app targets an API that is 2.0

Comment: Changing to 3.5 is not a problem, it is completely compatible with 2.0.  Of course we can't make you spend those 2 seconds of your life, you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [Redistributable package for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6442).